# Keras model summary incorrect

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am doing data augmentation using

```
data_gen=image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=20,width_shift_range=0.2,height_shift_range=0.2,
                                  zoom_range=0.15,horizontal_flip=False)

iter=data_gen.flow(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=64)
```

`data_gen.flow()` needs a rank 4 data matrix, so the shape of `X_train` is`(60000, 28, 28, 1)`. We need to pass the same shape i.e `(60000, 28, 28, 1)`while defining the architecture of the model as follows;

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal',input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Flatten())    
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.summary()
```

`model.add(Flatten())` was used to handle the rank-2 problem. Now the problem is with `model.summary()`. It is giving incorrect output as shown below;

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 28, 28, 64)        128       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 50176)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                501770    
=================================================================
Total params: 501,898
Trainable params: 501,898
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The `Output Shape` for `dense_1 (Dense)` should be `(None,64)` and `Param #` should be `(28*28*64)+64` i.e `50240`. The `Output Shape` for  `dense_2 (Dense)` is correct but the `Param #` should be `(64*10)+10`i.e `650`.

Why is this happening and how can this problem be addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summary is not incorrect. The keras `Dense` layer always works on the last dimension of the input.

ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense

> Input shape:
>
> N-D tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., input_dim). The most common situation would > be a 2D input with shape (batch_size, input_dim).
>   Output shape:
>
> N-D tensor with shape: (batch_size, ..., units). For instance, for a 2D input with 
>   shape (batch_size, input_dim), the output would have shape (batch_size, units).

Before each Dense layer, you need to manually apply `Flatten()` to make sure you're passing 2-d data.

One work-around for your desired output_shape is:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='linear', use_bias = False, trainable = False, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones(),input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu'))    
model.add(Dense(units=10,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.summary()
```

The first layer is just one layer, initialized with ones, with no bias, so it just multiplies the input with one and passes to the next layer to be flattened. This removes unnecessary parameters from the model.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 28, 28, 1)         2         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 784)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,892
Trainable params: 50,892
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Does `Output Shape` of  `(None, 28, 28, 1)` means it is `4-D`? What if `X_train` is `(60000, 28, 28, 3)`? What should be the `Output Shape` in that case? Also for the first layer `W=1` which is broadcasted to the shape of the input matrix `(28,28,1)`. So in that case shouldn't the  `Param # = 28*28*1+1=785` rather than `Param # =2`?

Comment: both are 4-D, not the output shape but the input shape for a dense should be 2-d (batch_dim, features). param should be 2 because 28*28*1 is the input and no weight/biases needed for them.

Comment: You have used weights here `kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones()` so shouldn't the weight matrix be of the size `(28,28,1)`? We perform element-wise multiplication between `X_train` and `W` which have the same shape.

Comment: Another thing to consider here is that during backpropagation the weights for the first layers which were earlier `1` as a result of `kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.Ones()` will now be updated. So now basically we have added one more hidden layer whose weights will be updated during every epoch. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Element wise multiplication betweeen an input and a dense with 1 unit, here, you can consider the dense as a scalar, only that scalar is learnt, that's why.

Comment: You can just set `trainable = False` in the first layer, so it's not updated.

Comment: ok, this can be done but as far as your comment, "Element wise multiplication betweeen an input and a dense with 1 unit, here, you can consider the dense as a scalar, only that scalar is learnt, that's why". I am not clear about it, please explain. Meanwhile, let me accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: In the first layer, there is only one scalar (1), the input (shape: 28*28*1) is getting multiplied with that scalar value (1), a matrix of shape (28*28) gets multiplied by a scalar value 1, so the flattened output should be of same dimension, right? - yes, it's same 28828 = 784. The only parameter in this case is the 1 scalar value (1 neuron), that's why we have only 2 parameters in layer 1 (+1 for bias). There's no matrix weight involved here, it's the first layer.

Comment: If you're still confused, ask a separate question - which may clarify things up.