# Learning with Batch Normalization vs without Batch Normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, batch-normalization

The primary objective of Batch Normalization is its faster optimization speed. To confirm it, I created a model with and without batch normalization as shown below;

**Without BN:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='linear',use_bias=False,kernel_initializer=init_1,input_shape=(28,28,1),trainable=False))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1024,kernel_initializer=init_2))
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10,kernel_initializer=init_2))
model.add(Activation(activation='softmax'))
```

**With BN:**

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='linear',use_bias=False,kernel_initializer=init_1,input_shape=(28,28,1),trainable=False))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=1024,kernel_initializer=init_2))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation(activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=10,kernel_initializer=init_2))
model.add(Activation(activation='softmax'))
```

The model was then compiled and trained on augmented data as shown below;

```
opt=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(iter,steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(len(X_train)/64),epochs=30)
```

To my surprise, I found that the model **Without BN converges faster**.

To further confirm the findings, I tried it by varying the number of units in the hidden layer and got the following results(this time using fit() method rather than fit_generator() and using the original data rather than augmented data);

**No. of hidden units = 5** 
[image]

**No. of hidden units = 50** 
[image]

**No. of hidden units = 100** 
[image]

From the graphs, we can observe that the model seems to converge faster without batch normalization and achieves higher accuracy than that being achieved with normalization.

Please help me in finding out where I am doing it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554123/keras-model-summary-incorrect/61554183?noredirect=1#comment108886013_61554183

Comment: To be frank, you can claim anything with such a dummy setup. Claims should be supported with experiments that repeat for a large enough set. Btw. what's with the first layer: multiplying input with a scalar, what's your init1 and init2? Also, it's clearly visible as you increase hidden units, with batch norm performs better, you just unnecessarily trained for more epochs to claim something which is probably just not there.